# javascript data getting undefined

Tags: javascript

Variable `CIMtrek_Attachement_1` getting undefined it is not checking the if condition it moving to this line `var selecteditems = CIMtrek_Attachement_1.split("\\");`

```
var CIMtrek_Attachement_1= $("#CIMtrek_RegWhseCo_Attachement_1").val();

            alert("CIMtrek_Attachement_1=666666==>> "+CIMtrek_Attachement_1);
            if (CIMtrek_Attachement_1 !== null && CIMtrek_Attachement_1 !== "" && CIMtrek_Attachement_1 === undefined)
            {
                var selecteditems = CIMtrek_Attachement_1.split("\\");

                var filename = selecteditems[(selecteditems.length-1)];

                alert("selecteditems=666==>> "+selecteditems);
                alert("filename=66666==>> "+filename);

                nodeField = createNodeField(xmlDoc, new Array("FieldName"), "Record")
                nodeField.attributes[0].value = NewFormFields[i]

                nodeField.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(filename));

                rootElement.appendChild(nodeField);
            }
```

Comment: the div with id="CIMtrek_RegWhseCo_Attachement_1" exists in the html?

Comment: so, you are not getting the value in the alert then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `typeof(CIMtrek_Attachement_1) === undefined` :) and shouldn't it be !== instead of === ?

Comment: not equal to undefined and null and empty string to that particular field

Comment: just asking because you have: not null, not empty and equal undefined instead of not equal undefined

Comment: Yes Thanks for instruction